# "I'd chase him down" vs. "I had to chase him down"

Tags: contraction-vs-full-form

I was reading an article and I encountered this sentence:

> Sometimes the warchief target would run off and **I'd chase him down** a field for longer than I care to admit.

To me, if I remove the contraction I also have to add the word "to" (I had to chase him down) so the sentence makes sense.

Is this correct or the meaning changes completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You feel that because you're probably forgetting that *I'd* can also mean *I would*.

Because *chase* is in the present tense and also because *to* is not in the phrase, the correct uncontracted form is *I would chase him down*.

So yes, the meaning changes completely in this case.

There is also [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56629/how-can-we-distinguish-between-i-would-and-i-had-if-someone-says-id) which explains the use of *I would* vs. *I had* in contracted form.

Answer (score 1):

I'd chase him down is the contraction for *I would chase him down*

[would](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1837_aae/page9.shtml) in this case indicates an action repeated in the past.