# Infinitive after had

Tags: past-tense

Why is in this sentence didn't use past participle of the verb give:

> He'd give a doorman a 100$ just for opening the door.

Sentence if from the film Goodfellas.

Comment: That's he *would* give a doorman . . .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we distinguish between "I would" and "I had" if someone says "I'd"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56629/how-can-we-distinguish-between-i-would-and-i-had-if-someone-says-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us analyze the sentence. The sentence starts with "He'd," which is a contraction of "He had" or "He would." It appears that in the movie, the Subject(the $ giver) had a generously lavish habit of rewarding doormen with a $100 bill. It was a recurring habit, not a one-off or single instance. Since it was a recurring habit or action, the contraction "he'd" expands to "he would," i.e., "He would give a doorman a $100 just for opening the door" - a regular habit. We decoded the contraction as "he would," therefore, using the past participle of "give" which is "given" would not make sense depending on the tense and context used by the movie script writer.

Comment: Even if no one ever had such a habit, the implication is that he *would* theoretically make an exaggerated gesture like that.

Answer (score 0):

**He'd** not only means **"He had "**, but it also means **" He would "**.  Here it means "He would ".